# Apply a function to a pandas dataframe column, considering values of previous rows

Tags: python, pandas

```
df:

375ma

NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
123
124
168
189
190
200
```

How to use the following function to get values for every 20/xx entries in `375ma`?

```
def trendline(data, order=1):
    coeffs = np.polyfit(data.index.values, list(data), order)
    slope = coeffs[-2]
    return float(slope)
```

If I do:

```
df['trend'] = trendline(df['375ma'][-5:])
```

I get the same value all in all rows.

I can probably use a `for` loop to do this, is there a different way to do this?

Edit:

The `[-5:]` is so that the function looks into 5 values preceding in 375ma column.

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of `[:-5]`?

Comment: @Itay `[-5:]` is to use the five preceding values. I tried the apply suggested by you. I get TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html) your function after, having the parameter `raw` set to `False` to pass a series in the function, such as:

```
df['trend'] = df['375ma'].rolling(5).apply(trendline, raw=False)

print (df)
   375ma  trend
0    NaN    NaN
1    NaN    NaN
2    NaN    NaN
3    NaN    NaN
4  123.0    NaN
5  124.0    NaN
6  168.0    NaN
7  189.0    NaN
8  190.0   19.9
9  200.0   17.4
```